# ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT

Tags: npm, angular-cli

While running the following command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I am getting below exception:

> npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT npm ERR! network
>   request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason:
>   connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.16.35:80 npm ERR! network This is a problem
>   related to network connectivity. npm ERR! network In most cases you
>   are behind a proxy or have bad network settings. npm ERR! network npm
>   ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the npm
>   ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my issue referring below:

https://fak3r.com/2015/07/31/howto-use-npm-behind-a-corporate-proxy/

but instead of setting registry value = http://registry.npmjs.org/

I used below, which worked:

```
proxy=http://Company Proxy:80/
https_proxy=https://Company Proxy:80/
strict-ssl=false
ca=null
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```